# Changing hue and lightness in Lab, Hcl or any perceptually uniform color system

Tags: javascript, math, language-agnostic, colors, color-picker

Changing hue, saturation and lightness in HSL color space if very easy.
See [this javascript implementation for example](https://github.com/harthur/color).

It is also easy to generate color schemes like: analogous, monochromatic, triad, tetrad, etc.
See [this javascript implementation](http://bgrins.github.com/TinyColor/).

The problem is that the HSL color system is not perceptually uniform.
And actually that's a real problem.

If you don't know what I am talking about, it's ok. 
Read about it: [here](http://boronine.com/2012/03/26/Color-Spaces-for-Human-Beings/) and [here](http://vis4.net/blog/posts/avoid-equidistant-hsv-colors/). (these two articles are really short but very valuable, you really should read them).

The solution is using a color space that is perceptually uniform, like: CieLab, CieLuv, or Hcl.

The problem is that these color spaces also have colors that are out of the gamut(colors that cannot be displayed).

For working with different color spaces in javascript check out [chroma.js](https://github.com/gka/chroma.js) or [chromatist](https://github.com/jrus/chromatist).

After this little introduction here is my actual problem:

I want to generate perceptually uniform color schemes(analogous, triad, tetrad, complementary, etc.). As I mentioned in Hsl it is simple: for example to generate a triad scheme I just rotate the HUE with 120 then with 240 and I have a triad scheme.

Well, in CieLab, Hcl or CieLuv it is not that simple. In Hcl (Hue, Chroma, Lightness) if I rotate Hue with 120 grades without changing chroma and lightness it is possible that the generated color will be not displayable (will be outside of RGB space).

Let's summarize the question:

**How can I generate color schemes in a perceptually uniform color system (like CieLab, Hcl, CieLuv, or any other perceptually uniform color space)?**

I want to implement this in javascript, but basically I want to find the method, so the question is language independent.

I hope we can find a clever way together :)

Comment: Inappropriate here. Ask it to a group of color scientists instead. The very fact that you say it is language independent means it is OT here.

Comment: Rather than calling them black holes, I'd suggest using the common phrase for the issue, that these colors are out of the gamut of a given set.

Comment: Finally, you need to define what your goal is more clearly, in terms of a color scheme in a space like Lab. Once you have done that, the solution will usually be obvious. But without that definition, the problem is clearly impossible, and the people to help you WITH that definition are surely color scientists. So again, it is OT here.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, changed it. As I sad I need a javascript implementation, but if a c# guy has an idea, it is welcomed. I will also ask on math forums, but wanted to ask here too, because I want a "coding solution", and maybe some programmers already have experience with this.

Comment: It is NOT a math forum question. It is NOT a c# question. It is NOT a javascript question. It IS a problem of definition, purely a color science question. You need to decide how to work with the gamuts in question.

Comment: Let me see if I can explain this another way. This is not a question of HOW to implement a given algorithm in Javascript. It IS a question of WHAT algorithm you need to implement in the first place, and that based on color science issues. It has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Woodchips, I got you point! Calm down. You explained in four comments that this is off topic, you downvoted, and voted to close. Thank you for expressing you point of view, now let the community decide if my question will be closed or not. Yes, this is not a "strictly programming" question, but maybe programmers can help me find an "algorithm" for this. I got your point, you don't need to write another dozen of comments. Do something better: It's valentines day!

Comment: @TamasPap it seems like you were worried about people suggesting to use RGB and other colorspaces, thus you wasted a lot of space pointing out cute references. Consequently, people interested in the subject might have ignored the question altogether. I don't have time to post a refined answer here, but the paper "Retrieval For Color Artistry Concepts" (by Lay and Guan) handles the problem described.

Comment: what's with the hate? this is a good question with good references. and even a solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem based on HUSL (Human Friendly HSL) color space. This color space isn't perfectly perceptually uniform, but it's very close to it.

You can learn more about it here:

http://boronine.com/husl/